# how to take distinct values from a table column and Insert new rows for these values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table named Function_Access where there are three columns - `ID` , `function` , `Access_level`.

I want to insert data for each function for a new ID . There are 1000 or more functions available in the table .

For All functions there would be an entry and the `Access level` would be `NULL` at the first entry later we can update the table with the actual (Read/write) `Access_Level`.

How to insert into the tables for 1000 or more functions easily without using 1000 or more insert statements ?

Comment: Where would the `function`s come from?

Answer (score 0):

If ID is an identity column, or has a default value which is being handled some other way, you could simply do:

```
INSERT Function_Access (function)
SELECT DISTINCT function
FROM Function_Access;
```

Comment: At least in ANSI SQL the INTO keyword is missing.

Comment: So you mean SQL Server doesn't need INTO? (I'm just curious.)